# PHP Image counter number formatting

Tags: php, image, counter, number-formatting

I'm building a counter that counts and displays on a web page the number of images in a certain directory.

The code I'm currently using is this:

```
<?
    $d = opendir("images/myimagefolder");
$count = 0;
     $min_digits = 7;
while(($f = readdir($d)) !== false)
  if(ereg('.jpg$', $f))
     ++$count;
closedir($d);
 if ($min_digits)
{
  $count = sprintf('%0'.$min_digits.'f', $count);
}

$number = $count;
$formattedNumber = sprintf("%07d", $number);
$formattedNumber = str_split($formattedNumber, 3);
$formattedNumber = implode(",", $formattedNumber);

  print "$formattedNumber";
?>
```

This works well and outputs a number like the following: 000,000,5

What I am wanting is to have the separating commas occur every 3 digits from the right not the left, so it would appear as 0,000,005

How would this this be done?

I have tried a number of modifications to my sprintf and str_split code but nothing has worked so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

//image count
$images=count(glob("images/myimagefolder/*.jpg"));

//padding
$images=sprintf("%07s",$images);

//commas
$images=strrev(implode(",",str_split(strrev($images),3)));

//outputs 0,000,005
echo $images;

?>
```

Had a bit of fun coming up with the shortest possible way to accomplish your solution. :)

Comment: Thanks Sean, this is great and does clean up the code a bit, hence I've marked it as my "accepted" answer. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$formattedNumber = sprintf("%07d", $number);
$formattedNumber = str_split(strrev($formattedNumber), 3);
for (i=0;i<count($formattedNumber); i++)
    $formattedNumber[i] = strrev($formattedNumber[i]);
$formattedNumber = implode(",", array_reverse($formattedNumber));
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Drop the last four lines. All you need is 'print number_format ($count);'

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

**Edit, the above won't work with the leading 0's**

I found this in the comments on the php site. A little regex magic should do it in one line.

```
print preg_replace("/(?<=\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/",",",$count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take with arrays:

```
$num    = sprintf("%07d", 5);
$digits = str_split($num, 1);
$digits = array_reverse($digits);
$chunks = array_map('array_reverse', array_reverse(array_chunk($digits, 3)));

$concat_chunks = array();
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    $concat_chunks[] = join('', $chunk);
}

$output = join(',', $concat_chunks);
print $output;
```